# What happens to linear terms like $\langle \psi| \hat{a}\cdot \vec{\sigma} | \psi \rangle$ in CHSH inequality?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, bells-inequality, foundations

The CHSH inequality is given by (e.g., 4.33 [here](http://theory.caltech.edu/%7Epreskill/ph229/notes/chap4_01.pdf))

$$\langle E_a E_b\rangle + \langle E_{a^\prime} E_b\rangle + \langle E_a E_{b^\prime}\rangle - \langle E_{a^\prime} E_{b^\prime}\rangle \le 2,$$
where $E_a=(I +\hat{a}\cdot \vec{\sigma})/2, E_{a^\prime}=(I + \hat{a}^\prime\cdot \vec{\sigma})/2, E_b=(I+\hat{b}\cdot \vec{\sigma})/2, E_{b^\prime}=(I+\hat{b}^\prime\cdot \vec{\sigma})/2$.

Take for example the first term $\langle a b\rangle = \langle \psi |(I + \hat{a}\cdot \vec{\sigma}) (I + \hat{b}\cdot \vec{\sigma}) |\psi\rangle $. Apart from a factor of (1/2), it is often written as $1 + \langle \psi | ( \hat{a}\cdot \vec{\sigma}) ( \hat{b}\cdot \vec{\sigma}) |\psi\rangle  = 1 + \cos(\theta_{ab})$. The first term is clearly $\langle \psi | \psi \rangle = 1$, but what happens to the terms like $\langle \psi| \hat{a}\cdot \vec{\sigma} | \psi \rangle$ and $\langle \psi| \hat{b}\cdot \vec{\sigma} | \psi \rangle$ ?

Comment: I believe in the notes the expression given is $\langle \psi | ( \hat{a}\cdot \vec{\sigma}) ( \hat{b}\cdot \vec{\sigma}) |\psi\rangle=-a\cdot b=-\cos\theta_{ab}$. The confusion arises because for a single qubit we would use the dot product property https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices#Relation_to_dot_and_cross_product but here each $\sigma$ acts on a different qubit, which always gives anticorrelations for the singlet state

Answer (score 2):

For a singlet state $|\psi\rangle$, each of the expectation values $\langle \sigma_i\rangle$ vanishes such that $\langle\psi|\vec{a}\cdot\vec{\sigma}|\psi\rangle=0$ for all vectors $\vec{a}$.

The notes referred to in this question explicitly assume the singlet state is being used "Recall that if Alice and Bob share the maximally-entangled state $|\psi_-\rangle$,
then . . ."

Comment: But there can be different possible singlet states. Can you prove it in general?

Comment: @User101 there is only one singlet state. You have already assumed it to be present when writing $\langle (a\cdot \sigma)(b\cdot \sigma)\rangle=a\cdot b=\cos\theta_{ab}$; otherwise, you must include all of the other terms explicitly

Comment: @User101 The expectation value $\langle \sigma_i\rangle$ only depends on the reduced density matrix of one party. For any maximally entangled state, this is the maximally mixed state (and thus $\langle \sigma_i\rangle = \mathrm{tr}\,\sigma_i/2= 0$).

Comment: @NorbertSchuch agreed. The question actually assumes the singlet state to achieve $\langle \psi | ( \hat{a}\cdot \vec{\sigma}) ( \hat{b}\cdot \vec{\sigma}) |\psi\rangle=\cos\theta_{ab}$ (although this correctly should yield $-\cos\theta_{ab}$); the other maximally entangled states don't have this perfect anticorrelation

Comment: @QuantumMechanic Agreed. My point was really just that the specific property asked for, $\langle \sigma_i \rangle = 0$, is a property satisfied by *any* maximally entangled state, and for a very simple reason, rather than one specific to the singlet state.